# Are fresh windows installs more anonymous/unlinkable than clones?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, privacy, clone

If you're using multiple virtual machines or VPS's with separate IP addresses to remain anonymous and unlinkable, is there any difference between doing fresh installs on each or doing a fresh install on one removing cookies and cloning?

Ignoring spyware, can websites see anything that would be consistent across clones, that would be different across fresh installs?

It's my understanding a website can't see the windows username, windows product key, windows machine id, disk volume serial number, hardware serial numbers (including hard drive, BIOS, MAC address), etc.  So, I'm thinking saving time with cloning is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit [Panopticlick](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHpPbr857LAhWHKJQKHS6UDGEQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpanopticlick.eff.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHO8TlRy7LtDj9w1bKGB2tZb9gZKA) and look at their fingerprinting, and, for anonymous browsing you would be better off using [TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/).

Depending on how you do the installs, timezones would be consistent between clones and possibly different between installs.  Depending on your timing and method of installing, software sub-versions may be different, as would browser plugin details.